# Make List Selection Copy Column Data from Another Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

With the help of the stack community I have developed a piece of code that takes each column heading in one workbook and creates a list of those headings in another workbook. Now I want a piece of code that will copy the entire column of the selected heading.

Here is the code that creates the list:

```
Private Sub Main()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
    Dim foldername As Variant
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    foldername = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If foldername <> False Then
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(foldername)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Dim destination As Worksheet
    Dim emptyColumn As Long
    Dim lastFullColumn As Long
    Dim emptyColumnLetter As String
    Dim lastFullColumnLetter As String
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets(1)
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets(1)
    Dim lastFullColumn1 As Long
    Dim lastFullColumn2 As Long

    Set destination = ws2

    'Find the last column with something on the first row
    lastFullColumn = destination.Cells(1,      destination.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If lastFullColumn > 1 Then
    emptyColumn = lastFullColumn + 1
    End If

     'Create the list with rows titles

    lastFullColumn1 = ws1.Cells(1, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lastFullColumn2 = ws2.Cells(1, ws2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

    Set rng1 = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, 1), ws1.Cells(1, lastFullColumn1))
    Set rng2 = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(1, lastFullColumn2),      ws2.Cells(lastFullColumn1, lastFullColumn2))

    rng2.Value2 = Application.Transpose(rng1)

    With ws2.Range("E14").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & rng2.Address
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = "LIST"
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
    End With
    End If
End Sub
```

And for the code that makes the list copy when a selection is selected, I was thinking something along these lines, but I can't quite get it to work:

```
Sub CopyHeadings()

    If Target.Address = Range("E14").Address Then
    For i = 1 To lastFullColumn1
    If Range("E14").Value = Range(i).Value Then
         wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(i).Copy destination:=wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(emptyColumn)

    End If
    Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

I feel like looping across the first row through all the columns in the first workbook, then if it comes across a value that matches the value in the cell on workbook 2 where the list is, having it copy that entire column from workbook 1 to the next open column on the second workbook would work, but if someone has a better plan of attack, I'd love to hear it, Thanks!

So I tried going off of your example and this is what I have:

```
Public Sub CopyHeadings(ByRef ws1 As Worksheet, ByRef ws2 As Worksheet,  Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastFullColumn1 As Long
    Dim rngE14 As Range

    Set rngE14 = ws2.Range("E14").Value
    lastFullColumn1 = ws1.Cells(1, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    If Target.Address = ws2.Range("E14").Address Then
        For i = 1 To lastFullColumn1
            If rngE14 = ws1.Range(i).Value Then ws1.Columns(i).Copy ws2.Columns(i)
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

It isn't returning any errors, but it still isn't copying and pasting any information from ws1 to ws2.  It just has me choose a macro, and then it runs that macro.  CopyHeadings doesn't come up on the list though of macros to run though.

Comment: How do you call `CopyHeadings()` (from where?)

Comment: @paulbica What do you mean from where?  Is there some more syntax I need to add so the code can share info with the other sub?

Comment: Correct: `lastFullColumn1` and `emptyColumn` are not defined in the scope of `CopyHeadings()`. You also need to fully qualify all ranges to show what sheet they belong to, and you also need those sheets as parameters when you call the function, as well as the Target. I will post an answer shortly, to show you how to accomplish all this, but you will need to adjust it so it matches your sheets

Comment: I'm pretty sure I defined everything and set the variables and all that, but when I got to run my CopyHeadings sub, it just has me choose a macro, but nothing happens.  Am I missing a key point here?  Thanks

Comment: you'll find details in my answer

Comment: I made an edit to my original question, I still am having trouble getting it to work.  Thanks for all your help, I think I'm almost there!

Answer (score 1):

There are variables out of scope in sub `CopyHeadings` (this is not tested so adjust it accordingly)

```
Public Sub CopyHeadings(ByRef ws1 As Worksheet, ByRef ws2 As Worksheet, Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long, lastCol1 As Long, rngE14 As Range

    rngE14 = ws2.Range("E14").Value
    lastCol1 = ws1.Cells(1, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    If Target.Address = ws2.Range("E14").Address Then
        For i = 1 To lastCol1
            If rngE14 = ws1.Range(i).Value Then ws1.Columns(i).Copy ws2.Columns(i)
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Test sub:

```
Public Sub testColumnCopy()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, fileID As Variant

    fileID = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If fileID <> False Then
        Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set ws2 = Workbooks.Open(fileID).Sheets("Sheet1")
        CopyHeadings ws1, ws2, ws2.Range("E14")
    End If
End Sub
```

---

.

Your main sub:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Main()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, rng1 As Range
    Dim wb2 As Workbook, ws2 As Worksheet, rng2 As Range
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet, fileID As Variant, emptyCol As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long, lastCol1 As Long, lastCol2 As Long
    Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
    fileID = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If fileID <> False Then
        Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(fileID)
        Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set wsDest = ws2
        'Last column containing data
        lastCol = wsDest.Cells(1, wsDest.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If lastCol > 1 Then emptyCol = lastCol + 1
        'Create the list with rows titles
        lastCol1 = ws1.Cells(1, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        lastCol2 = ws2.Cells(1, ws2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        Set rng1 = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, 1), ws1.Cells(1, lastCol1))
        Set rng2 = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(1, lastCol2), ws2.Cells(lastCol1, lastCol2))
        rng2.Value2 = Application.Transpose(rng1)
        With ws2.Range("E14").Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & rng2.Address
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = "LIST"
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```